# Android SQLite Database Design

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing an Android menu app for a restaurant. It should only show categories and items of each category for display purposes. I want them to edit the categories and items anytime.

SQLite database is the option I would go with currently, but I have a problem. For example, Breakfast, Salads, Appetizers etc.. are in the categories sql table. Then, there is another sql table for Breakfast's items and another for Salads's items etc.. and each item would include a picture, title, and a price.

Now, Lets say they could add to the categories table a new category, how about that category's items table? how can it be added automatically? Is there a better way to go about this problem?

Comment: Why does each category have its own table?

Comment: each category has its own table?

Comment: How would you model the objects in Java? If you can figure that out, then maybe Realm would be a better option. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: Stefan, njzk2, Correct me if I'm wrong, storing items list as a column of a category isn't a good practice. That's why I thought to make new items table for each category.

Comment: I don't understand what those people thinking putting the question on hold after it's already answered, "too broad" ? read carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a table for each category.

Two tables - categories and items. The Items table holds a [foreign key](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) to the category.

Category

```
_id | Name
----| ------
1   | Breakfast
2   | Lunch
3   | Dinner
```

Items

```
_id | name      | cat_id | price
--- | --------- | ------ | -----
1   | Bagels    |  1     |  1.00
2   | Salmon    |  3     |  14.99
```

**Example queries**

To find all dinner items,

```
SELECT name,price from Items where cat_id = 3;
```

How many lunch items on the menu

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from Items WHERE cat_id = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much more elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

I would model the problem (assuming I understand it correctly) with these tables:

```
Categories table with columns - id, name, (any additional you need)
CategoryItems table with columns - id, categoryId, name, (any additional you need)
```

categoryId is a FK to the Categories table. That way your items will always refer back to the proper category they belong to. All you will have to do is ensure that when someone adds a new category, that when you add new items, you properly populate the categoryId along with each new item.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This seems a good design choice, but can you elaborate more on the FK?

Comment: categoryId relates to the Categories id column - that's what I mean by the FK (foreign key in database parlance)